# My Naive Bayes classifier works for my model but will not accept user input on my application

Tags: python, classification, sentiment-analysis, naivebayes, countvectorizer

I am trying to deploy my machine learning Naive Bayes sentiment analysis model onto a web application. The idea is that the user should type some text, which the application performs sentiment analysis on and then stores the text with the assigned sentiment in another column within the database, to be called as a list via html later.

While the model and vectorizer work fine on Google Colab, when I load the model to my application and try to run the user input through it it won't work. I have gotten many error codes depending on the different solutions I've tried.

The most recent is:

```
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

But when I try to fix this I get other error messages such as:

```
'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

or:

```
ValueError: X has 1 features, but MultinomialNB is expecting 26150 features as input.
```

or:

```
sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: Vocabulary not fitted or provided
```

BASICALLY I don't know what I'm doing and I've been trying to figure it out for weeks. My inclination is that the problem is either the format coming in from the user is not readable by the model, or the vectorizer is not working on the input.

OR maybe my whole approach is wrong, and there are steps I am missing. Any help with this would be massively appreciated.

My model code looks like this (after preprocessing):

```
#Split into training and testing data
x = df['text']
y = df['sentiment']

df1 = df[df["text"].notnull()]
x1 = df1['text']
y1 = df1['sentiment']

x1_train, x1_test, y1_train, y1_test = train_test_split(x1, y1, test_size=0.2, random_state=30)

# Vectorize text
vec = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')
x1 = vec.fit_transform(x1).toarray()
x1_test = vec.transform(x1_test).toarray()

df1 = df1.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)

from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

sentiment_model = MultinomialNB()
sentiment_model.fit(x1, y1)
sentiment_model.score(x1_test, y1_test)

# Save model to disk
pickle.dump(sentiment_model, open('sentiment_model.pkl','wb'))
```

And my application code looks like this:

```
@app.route('/journal', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def entry():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        journals = request.form
        
        entry_date = journals['entry_date']
        journal_entry = journals['journal_entry']

        vec = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')
        sdf = pd.DataFrame('journal_entry')
        sdf = vec.fit_transform(sdf).toarray()
        sdf = vec.transform(sdf).toarray()

        sentiment = sentiment_model.predict(sdf)
        journals['sentiment'] = sentiment

        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        #insert the values with sentiment attribute into database
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO journals(entry_date, journal_entry, sentiment) VALUES(%s, %s, %s)",(entry_date, journal_entry, sentiment))
        mysql.connection.commit()
   
    return render_template('journal.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems to me that there are multiple issues here at play.

For one, `sdf = pd.DataFrame('journal_entry')` does not make sense -- you create the data frame from literal string 'journal_entry', not the actual contents of it? I suggest you get rid of the DataFrame in your `entry` function entirely, as it is not a required input structure for sklearn objects.

Secondly, you're duplicating functionality with calling `fit_transform` and then again `transform` in your `entry` function. It's sufficient to call `fit_transform` as it's doing two things: 1) it learns the dictionary 2) it transforms to document-term matrix.

Thirdly, you trained your model using a specific CountVectorizer model. This model will transform each document into vectors using the learned document-term matrix which acquires a fixed size at the time you call `fit` or `fit_transform` function. Then your Naive Bayes model is trained using this fixed sized vector. Hence, it complains when it gets a different sized vector at inference time -- this is because you're re-initializing `CountVectorizer` again at each `entry` call. You need to save the `CountVectorizer` as well if you want to preserve the feature size.

Also, I'd suggest making some check in your `entry` function that makes sure you get valid strings for your algorithm in the POST request.

```py
# load both CountVectorizer and the model 
vec = pickle.load(open("my_count_vec.pkl", "rb"))
sentiment_model = pickle.load(open("my_sentiment_model", "rb"))

@app.route('/journal', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def entry():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        journals = request.form
        
        entry_date = journals['entry_date']
        journal_entry = journals['journal_entry']
        sdf = vec.transform([journal_entry]).reshape(1, -1)
        sentiment = sentiment_model.predict(sdf)
        ...
```

`sdf = vec.transform([journal_entry]).reshape(1, -1)` assumes that journal entry is a single string and hence it needs reshaping for further processing.

Comment: thank you for your response it has helped me a lot to clean up my code. One thing I'm struggling with is how to formulate putting the vectorizer into a function so I can load it into my API with the model. Should I split and transform the data within the function? And if so how do I call the vectorizer when I'm fitting sentiment_model? Thanks again

Comment: I got that sorted and it's now working! I did get an error, 'TypeError: 'ImmutableMultiDict' objects are immutable', but was able to solve this by changing 'journals = request.form' to 'journals = request.form.to_dict()'. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Data Science pipelines can be tricky for those starting this journey. There is only one major issue with the current code. You are recreating your preprocessing step with every new incoming data. The vectoriser you train your model is no longer used and thus mismatch of features. Remember, we only `.fit_tranform` during fitting/training. When we use it, we only `.transform`.

You can fix it by saving your trained vectoriser just as you did with your model. Both model and vectoriser will then be used on API endpoints `model.predict(vec.transform(data))`.

A better way is to merge your preprocess(vectoriser) and classifier as one.

```py
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

sentiment_model = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        (
            "count_verctorizer",CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')
        ),
        (
            "naive_bayes", MultinomialNB()
       )
])

# now, it performs transformation in a pipeline 

sentiment_model.fit(X1, y1)

# now we can use it/save it to use in our API we’re you will only need the model as the model will do `vectorizer tranform` for you
```

On the API, you can ensure the other steps of filtering if no values and regex are also performed. You can add these to pipelines if you want.

```
...

journal_entry = journals['journal_entry']
X = pd.DataFrame(journal_entry) # this should be like your X1
X = X.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
X = X[X ["text"].notnull()]

# assuming we have loaded our model

sentiment = sentiment_model.predict(X)
...
```

Comment: Hi @Prayson, thanks so much for the answer. I tried this solution but when I ran the pipeline code in the model I got the error ''numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower''.  Any idea of a fix for this?

Comment: Can you print the output of `type(X1)`, and a sample of `X1`?

Comment: Hey @Prayson I got it working thank you very much for the help! I hope you had a nice new years